Why does make_interval exist?
Is there a performance difference between these expressions?
select CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL '5 minutes';

select CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + make_interval(mins => 5);

I am wondering why make_interval exists.

For convenience, if the numbers involved are not constants. Compare these three equivalent expressions:
make_interval(hours => $1, mins => $1, secs => $1);

($1 || ' hours ' || $2 || ' minutes ' || $3 || ' seconds')::interval

(($1 * 60 + $2) * 60 + $3) * INTERVAL '1 second'

Which of them is easiest to read and maintain?
